# 'Clinch' used not for embrace but the romantic relationship itself?

Tags: metonyms

Is 'clinch' used not for embrace but the romantic relationship itself? I think I've heard it used, though I may be imagining it/misunderstanding.

Is it idiomatic enough to be something other than a metonym?

Comment: It's not given as a meaning in dictionaries, but I assume you already know that. Beyond that it's hard to prove a negative.

Comment: It doesn't seem familiar to me. And I didn't see it in the first screen of definitions on Urban Dictionary.

Comment: Metaphors, particularly phonosemantic metaphors, like the [_KL_-words](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/KL-chart.pdf), which have the sense of "together; contiguous; connected" can run into lots of senses. The personality mix of a relationship is separate from (but metaphorically and phonosemantically parallel to) the physical intimacy involved.

Comment: Putting aside "imagining it/misunderstanding," we generally don't give much weight here to **I think I've heard it used** by one person at one time. One swallow does not a Spring make.

Comment: Some examples would definitely be useful, even if they're from personal experience/communications. Or at least more of an idea of how it is used, if you want to make up a sentence (noun, verb...). Without that, we may be stuck for an answer.

Comment: Please show which dictionaries you have checked in, luke: 'This sense is not given in M-W, Collins, Wiktionary, CD, Macmillan' say would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps related, there's describing a romantic partner as a "main squeeze" or just "squeeze".

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly an unorthodox usage, but I think many readers would understand a writer's intent if they encountered "clinch" used to refer to a relationship. Connotation-wise, it would likely carry the imagery of its more common usage, so exercise discretion if imagery is particularly important to the sentence in question.

A trade relationship could maybe be called a clinch in some cases. "Not wanting to disturb the existing clinch between Nation A and Nation B, Nation C refrained from competing with their exports and maintained focus on trading with Nation D and Nation E in the interest of regional stability."

Comment: Using "clinch" to refer to the relationship between two countries, however, would be a metaphor rather than a literal description of the relationship. I think the metaphor might also refer to boxing or wrestling rather romantic encounter.